# Setting CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD to various values

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ library, that's intended to be usable across several compiler versions and several C++ standards. I have tests for this library - and I need to ensure that these tests pass for this matrix of compilers/versions that I wish to support.

I can provide `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=xx` (for 11, 14, 17) on the command line, and this seems to work fine. How do I provide a default value for this field? I would like that, if not provided by the user, that default is 11. It seems that when I do:

```
$ CXX=/path/to/gcc-7 cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
# does stuff, CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is 17

$ CXX=/path/to/gcc-7 cmake .. 
# does stuff, CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is still 17
```

which is counterintuitive to me. Is there a way to make the latter use the desired default value of 11?

Also, if I just rerun `cmake` with a different value in the same build directory, would that be enough to trigger a rebuild or would I need a new build directory?

Comment: Note that cmake caches some settings and don't update them if you just run `cmake` again. For some things you have to clear the build dir (or delete the CMakeCache.txt file and re-run `cmake`). Aldo note that when setting CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD, cmake (in its infinite wisdom - not) sets the "gnu-xx" version that allows compiler extensions (when using gcc at least) - that's not always what you want (I blame the cmake guys for that poor desition).

Comment: @JesperJuhl At least that last part I found how to fix! (`set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `[option][1]` command to let the user choose and give a default value yourself:

```
option(Barry_CXX_STANDARD "C++ standard" 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD Barry_CXX_STANDARD)
```

The variable name `Barry_CXX_STANDARD` indicated that it is specific to your project and should be the same prefix as all project-specific variables are named.
The downside of this approach is, that experienced CMake users would be surprised and set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` directly.

Another approach is to check whether the variable is set.

```
if(NOT "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif()
```

If CMake provides already a variable, I would use the second approach. If it is only your project-specific variable, the first one is better.

In any case, if you want to change the value you have to delete the `CMakeCache.txt` in your build directory. Otherwise the caching hides the change.

Comment: @usr1234569 In option() command, 1st parameter is name of variable, 3rd is its value. what is 2nd parameter ("C++ standard") ?

Comment: Its a help text, to indicate what's the purpose of the variable. For example the text is shown in the cmake gui.

Comment: The first approach seems doesn't work. When Barry_CXX_STANDARD is not specified in command line, I got OFF value instead of 11.
Documentation states, what `option` is for ON/OFF values only: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html

Answer (score 6):

In CMake world, *first invocation* of `cmake` **differs** from *later ones* (from the view of setting options in command line):

1. First invocation:

   - If option's value is given in command line(`-DOPTION=VALUE`), this value is used.
   - If option's value is not given in command line, default value is used.
2. Later invocations:

   - If option's value is given in command line(`-DOPTION=VALUE`), this value is used.
   - If option's value is not given in command line, **previous value** is used.
   - If option is *unset* (`-UOPTION`), *default value* is used.

Thus, having one `cmake` invocation already done, one may:

- **modify** some of options and leave other **unchanged**

  For doing that, pass modified options' values with `-D`.
- **reset** some of options and leave other **unchanged**

  For doing that, pass reset options' values with `-U`.
- **set** some options, and reset others to **default** values

  For doing that, make a *clean* rebuild by removing `CMakeCache.txt` from build directory or removing all files from build directory.

---

For assign default value for an option in the project, use common *CACHE* variables:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 CACHE STRING "C++ standard to be used")
```